# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and onActivityResult

Tags: android

My activity stack is A B C, with C at the top. A started B using startActivityForResult().

Now, in C, it starts A and clears the top using the following code:

```
        finish();

        intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

My question is, will onActivityResult() in A be called after the code above is executed? I expected it will, because B is destroyed after C starts A and clears the top. But, my test code showed that onActivityResult() in A was not called. I am confused. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Kai, the docs for CLEAR_TOP say "all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent."  However, I suspect that "closed" is a poor choice of words in the doc.. Android does not usually 'close' Activities unless memory demands it or they call finish().  This may require some testing.. I'm interested in seeing what you find.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are starting a new Activity A, from ACTIVITY C. This will not call the onActivityResult. This simply because a **new Activity A** is started. onActivityResult() will be called only when u finish() your Acitivity B.

I hope someone adds more to the anwsers, if this doesn make it clear.

Comment: onActivityResult() will be "Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation. " The doc didn't say onActivityResult() depends on finish().

Comment: practically u can exit the activity by calling the finish(). And thats what the doc mean as I understand. And calling Activity A from Activity C with CLEAR TOP is going to create the Activity A again unless your activity A has the launchmode set to SINGLE TOP. So I think that what you want is not posiible.. And pls update if u find a solution to this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to set the launchMode of your Activity A to the value "singleTask", or use your flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
by default, Activity A's launchMode is standard, then a new instance of A will be created when you start A from C.